# Wildfly 10 web apps are not working showing a white screen in browser but deployments are enabled

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-10

I use Wildfly 10 and I have two web apps in deployment section of Admin Console. Suddenly, the web apps are not working
by browser. It delays too much, it shows a white screen. I see in Wildfly Admin console that two deployments
are green enabled so Wildfly service is on. If I disable and enable one deployment, it happens nothing.
The browser keeps showing white when I check the web app. The server.log file shows no errors.
So I killed Wildfly process and I executed standalone.sh and the web apps started to work. The memory used percentage on linux server is 30% aproximately.

What are possible reasons for this case?. Wildfly memory configuration, maybe?

Comment: Are you getting errors in the browser console?

Comment: Good question. It did not occur to me in that time about the output.

Comment: One result that I have in browser history is Error 502. Proxy Error, but there are other history items which doesn't give an http result like 500 or 200.

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69217696/edit) the question and add some information?  This doesn't sound like a Wildfly issue but that's not clear.  A 500 could be a bad deployment, a 502 could be something else.

Comment: I think the issue is related to Wildfly because it affects to every deployments in the web server not just one. I added the informartion about memory used percentage on linux server